# Convert imported CSS module class for style attribute

Tags: reactjs, react-css-modules

I want to import a style from CSS module file and assign it to `style` attribute, instead of writing it directly as inline style. The following code:

```
import styles from "./Calculator.module.css"

const Calculator = () => {
 return (
   // ...
   <Card style={styles.darkmode} />
   // ...
  );
};
```

Gives a `The style prop expects a mapping from style properties to values, not a string` error, because  `styles.darkmode` is just a name, not a JSON object. How could I convert the class name to a valid JSON object?

I've also read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42124298/convert-string-to-json-object-for-use-in-react-js-style-tag-style), but in that case, he got the JSON object itself, not just the name.

Comment: Did you try writing css as json file directly !? I  want to know the reason, so that I can help you better

Answer (score -1):

CSS modules return unique class names. You should be using `className`, instead of `style`:

```
<Card className={styles.darkmode} />
```

Comment: But due to CSS Specificity, I want to assign that style to `style`, not to `className`.

Comment: I thought the whole point of CSS modules is to have scoped CSS so you wouldn't have to override things. If you want to override something, why not just create a style object in the component? Why use CSS modules?

Comment: https://liefery-it-legacy.github.io/blog/2018/06/27/overriding-styles-with-CSS-modules.html